# Use selected value from dropdownlist in if statement Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

I need help with the following:

I am using laravel and I am trying to echo the value of selected drop-down list through an If statement.

But I am getting an error:

> Undefined index: cabin_selected

My Blade looks like this:

```
        <div class="form-group-row">
         <div class="col-sm-8">
          <select class="form-control" id="selectcabin" name="cabin_selected" required focus>
           <option value="" disabled selected>--- Select cabin ---</option>
              <option value="Economy">Economy</option>
              <option value="Business">Business</option>
         </select>  
       </div>
      </div>
```

The if statement:

```
      <?php      
          if ($_POST['cabin_selected'] === 'Economy') {
           // echo ,,,
          }
          elseif ( $_POST['cabin_selected'] === 'Business' ) {
          // echo ,,,,
          }
      ?>
```

Can anyone help, please...

Comment: To remove the error you can simply check ` isset($_POST['cabin_selected'])` in both if and else condition. ie, `if ( isset($_POST['cabin_selected']) && $_POST['cabin_selected'] === 'Economy')`

Comment: I have made the mentioned above change and i am getting the same error.

Comment: Please check the line of error and make sure that it is happening to the same line that you are checking.

Comment: Thank you very much ... the error was about the else... it works now. thank you again.

Comment: Sorry ,,,I still have an issue with echo statement ....

Comment: echo $_POST['cabin_selected']; i get nothing when Economy selected ! i am confused, its like conditions are not met. i select economy and nothing happens,

Comment: Because you are using the select property in select cabinet which value is null.. So remove selected and it serms to be work

Comment: Hello Tanvir, do you mean remove select from this line <select class="form-control" id="selectcabin" name="cabin_selected" > plus </select>, could you give me an example.please

Comment: Did you fixed the issuw @Mohamed

Comment: I didn't @Prifulnath, i searched a lot and i noticed that you can't do the check in Blade. you must use from and do the check in the controller once the data is sent through a submit button, so i change the interface. do you have any clues?